# Recording .wav files in android

Tags: java, android, audio, wav, android-audiorecord

I need to record the audio from mic into uncompressed `.wav` format in my android applcation. Below is a code I found for this purpose.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.media.MediaRecorder.AudioSource;
import android.util.Log;

public class ExtAudioRecorder 
{
    private final static int[] sampleRates = {44100, 22050, 11025, 8000};

    public static ExtAudioRecorder getInstanse(Boolean recordingCompressed)
    {
        ExtAudioRecorder result = null;

        if(recordingCompressed)
        {
            result = new ExtAudioRecorder(    false, 
                                            AudioSource.MIC, 
                                            sampleRates[3], 
                                            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                                            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        }
        else
        {
            int i=0;
            do
            {
                result = new ExtAudioRecorder(    true, 
                                                AudioSource.MIC, 
                                                sampleRates[i], 
                                                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                                                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

            } while((++i<sampleRates.length) & !(result.getState() == ExtAudioRecorder.State.INITIALIZING));
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
    * INITIALIZING : recorder is initializing;
    * READY : recorder has been initialized, recorder not yet started
    * RECORDING : recording
    * ERROR : reconstruction needed
    * STOPPED: reset needed
    */
    public enum State {INITIALIZING, READY, RECORDING, ERROR, STOPPED};

    public static final boolean RECORDING_UNCOMPRESSED = true;
    public static final boolean RECORDING_COMPRESSED = false;

    // The interval in which the recorded samples are output to the file
    // Used only in uncompressed mode
    private static final int TIMER_INTERVAL = 120;

    // Toggles uncompressed recording on/off; RECORDING_UNCOMPRESSED / RECORDING_COMPRESSED
    private boolean         rUncompressed;

    // Recorder used for uncompressed recording
    private AudioRecord     audioRecorder = null;

    // Recorder used for compressed recording
    private MediaRecorder   mediaRecorder = null;

    // Stores current amplitude (only in uncompressed mode)
    private int             cAmplitude= 0;

    // Output file path
    private String          filePath = null;

    // Recorder state; see State
    private State              state;

    // File writer (only in uncompressed mode)
    private RandomAccessFile randomAccessWriter;

    // Number of channels, sample rate, sample size(size in bits), buffer size, audio source, sample size(see AudioFormat)
    private short                    nChannels;
    private int                      sRate;
    private short                    bSamples;
    private int                      bufferSize;
    private int                      aSource;
    private int                      aFormat;

    // Number of frames written to file on each output(only in uncompressed mode)
    private int                      framePeriod;

    // Buffer for output(only in uncompressed mode)
    private byte[]                   buffer;

    // Number of bytes written to file after header(only in uncompressed mode)
    // after stop() is called, this size is written to the header/data chunk in the wave file
    private int                      payloadSize;

    /**
    *
    * Returns the state of the recorder in a RehearsalAudioRecord.State typed object.
    * Useful, as no exceptions are thrown.
    *
    * @return recorder state
    */
    public State getState()
    {
        return state;
    }

    /*
    *
    * Method used for recording.
    *
    */
    private AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener updateListener = new AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener()
    {
        public void onPeriodicNotification(AudioRecord recorder)
        {
            audioRecorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length); // Fill buffer
            try
            { 
                randomAccessWriter.write(buffer); // Write buffer to file
                payloadSize += buffer.length;
                if (bSamples == 16)
                {
                    for (int i=0; i<buffer.length/2; i++)
                    { // 16bit sample size
                        short curSample = getShort(buffer[i*2], buffer[i*2+1]);
                        if (curSample > cAmplitude)
                        { // Check amplitude
                            cAmplitude = curSample;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else    
                { // 8bit sample size
                    for (int i=0; i<buffer.length; i++)
                    {
                        if (buffer[i] > cAmplitude)
                        { // Check amplitude
                            cAmplitude = buffer[i];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "Error occured in updateListener, recording is aborted");
                //stop();
            }
        }

        public void onMarkerReached(AudioRecord recorder)
        {
            // NOT USED
        }
    };
    /** 
     * 
     * 
     * Default constructor
     * 
     * Instantiates a new recorder, in case of compressed recording the parameters can be left as 0.
     * In case of errors, no exception is thrown, but the state is set to ERROR
     * 
     */ 
    public ExtAudioRecorder(boolean uncompressed, int audioSource, int sampleRate, int channelConfig, int audioFormat)
    {
        try
        {
            rUncompressed = uncompressed;
            if (rUncompressed)
            { // RECORDING_UNCOMPRESSED
                if (audioFormat == AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
                {
                    bSamples = 16;
                }
                else
                {
                    bSamples = 8;
                }

                if (channelConfig == AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO)
                {
                    nChannels = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    nChannels = 2;
                }

                aSource = audioSource;
                sRate   = sampleRate;
                aFormat = audioFormat;

                framePeriod = sampleRate * TIMER_INTERVAL / 1000;
                bufferSize = framePeriod * 2 * bSamples * nChannels / 8;
                if (bufferSize < AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat))
                { // Check to make sure buffer size is not smaller than the smallest allowed one 
                    bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
                    // Set frame period and timer interval accordingly
                    framePeriod = bufferSize / ( 2 * bSamples * nChannels / 8 );
                    Log.w(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "Increasing buffer size to " + Integer.toString(bufferSize));
                }

                audioRecorder = new AudioRecord(audioSource, sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize);

                if (audioRecorder.getState() != AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)
                    throw new Exception("AudioRecord initialization failed");
                audioRecorder.setRecordPositionUpdateListener(updateListener);
                audioRecorder.setPositionNotificationPeriod(framePeriod);
            } else
            { // RECORDING_COMPRESSED
                mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);                
            }
            cAmplitude = 0;
            filePath = null;
            state = State.INITIALIZING;
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (e.getMessage() != null)
            {
                Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), e.getMessage());
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "Unknown error occured while initializing recording");
            }
            state = State.ERROR;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets output file path, call directly after construction/reset.
     *  
     * @param output file path
     * 
     */
    public void setOutputFile(String argPath)
    {
        try
        {
            if (state == State.INITIALIZING)
            {
                filePath = argPath;
                if (!rUncompressed)
                {
                    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(filePath);                    
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (e.getMessage() != null)
            {
                Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), e.getMessage());
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "Unknown error occured while setting output path");
            }
            state = State.ERROR;
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Returns the largest amplitude sampled since the last call to this method.
     * 
     * @return returns the largest amplitude since the last call, or 0 when not in recording state. 
     * 
     */
    public int getMaxAmplitude()
    {
        if (state == State.RECORDING)
        {
            if (rUncompressed)
            {
                int result = cAmplitude;
                cAmplitude = 0;
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    return mediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
                }
                catch (IllegalStateException e)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }


    /**
     * 
    * Prepares the recorder for recording, in case the recorder is not in the INITIALIZING state and the file path was not set
    * the recorder is set to the ERROR state, which makes a reconstruction necessary.
    * In case uncompressed recording is toggled, the header of the wave file is written.
    * In case of an exception, the state is changed to ERROR
    *      
    */
    public void prepare()
    {
        try
        {
            if (state == State.INITIALIZING)
            {
                if (rUncompressed)
                {
                    if ((audioRecorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) & (filePath != null))
                    {
                        // write file header

                        randomAccessWriter = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "rw");

                        randomAccessWriter.setLength(0); // Set file length to 0, to prevent unexpected behavior in case the file already existed
                        randomAccessWriter.writeBytes("RIFF");
                        randomAccessWriter.writeInt(0); // Final file size not known yet, write 0 
                        randomAccessWriter.writeBytes("WAVE");
                        randomAccessWriter.writeBytes("fmt ");
                        randomAccessWriter.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(16)); // Sub-chunk size, 16 for PCM
                        randomAccessWriter.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes((short) 1)); // AudioFormat, 1 for PCM
                        randomAccessWriter.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes(nChannels));// Number of channels, 1 for mono, 2 for stereo
                        randomAccessWriter.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(sRate)); // Sample rate
                        randomAccessWriter.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(sRate*bSamples*nChannels/8)); // Byte rate, SampleRate*NumberOfChannels*BitsPerSample/8
                        randomAccessWriter.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes((short)(nChannels*bSamples/8))); // Block align, NumberOfChannels*BitsPerSample/8
                        randomAccessWriter.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes(bSamples)); // Bits per sample
                        randomAccessWriter.writeBytes("data");
                        randomAccessWriter.writeInt(0); // Data chunk size not known yet, write 0

                        buffer = new byte[framePeriod*bSamples/8*nChannels];
                        state = State.READY;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "prepare() method called on uninitialized recorder");
                        state = State.ERROR;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    mediaRecorder.prepare();
                    state = State.READY;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "prepare() method called on illegal state");
                release();
                state = State.ERROR;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            if (e.getMessage() != null)
            {
                Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), e.getMessage());
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "Unknown error occured in prepare()");
            }
            state = State.ERROR;
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * 
     *  Releases the resources associated with this class, and removes the unnecessary files, when necessary
     *  
     */
    public void release()
    {
        if (state == State.RECORDING)
        {
            stop();
        }
        else
        {
            if ((state == State.READY) & (rUncompressed))
            {
                try
                {
                    randomAccessWriter.close(); // Remove prepared file
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "I/O exception occured while closing output file");
                }
                (new File(filePath)).delete();
            }
        }

        if (rUncompressed)
        {
            if (audioRecorder != null)
            {
                audioRecorder.release();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (mediaRecorder != null)
            {
                mediaRecorder.release();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * 
     * Resets the recorder to the INITIALIZING state, as if it was just created.
     * In case the class was in RECORDING state, the recording is stopped.
     * In case of exceptions the class is set to the ERROR state.
     * 
     */
    public void reset()
    {
        try
        {
            if (state != State.ERROR)
            {
                release();
                filePath = null; // Reset file path
                cAmplitude = 0; // Reset amplitude
                if (rUncompressed)
                {
                    audioRecorder = new AudioRecord(aSource, sRate, nChannels+1, aFormat, bufferSize);
                }
                else
                {
                    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                }
                state = State.INITIALIZING;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), e.getMessage());
            state = State.ERROR;
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * 
     * Starts the recording, and sets the state to RECORDING.
     * Call after prepare().
     * 
     */
    public void start()
    {
        if (state == State.READY)
        {
            if (rUncompressed)
            {
                payloadSize = 0;
                audioRecorder.startRecording();
                audioRecorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            }
            else
            {
                mediaRecorder.start();
            }
            state = State.RECORDING;
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "start() called on illegal state");
            state = State.ERROR;
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * 
     *  Stops the recording, and sets the state to STOPPED.
     * In case of further usage, a reset is needed.
     * Also finalizes the wave file in case of uncompressed recording.
     * 
     */
    public void stop()
    {
        if (state == State.RECORDING)
        {
            if (rUncompressed)
            {
                audioRecorder.stop();

                try
                {
                    randomAccessWriter.seek(4); // Write size to RIFF header
                    randomAccessWriter.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(36+payloadSize));

                    randomAccessWriter.seek(40); // Write size to Subchunk2Size field
                    randomAccessWriter.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(payloadSize));

                    randomAccessWriter.close();
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "I/O exception occured while closing output file");
                    state = State.ERROR;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                mediaRecorder.stop();
            }
            state = State.STOPPED;
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "stop() called on illegal state");
            state = State.ERROR;
        }
    }

    /* 
     * 
     * Converts a byte[2] to a short, in LITTLE_ENDIAN format
     * 
     */
    private short getShort(byte argB1, byte argB2)
    {
        return (short)(argB1 | (argB2 << 8));
    }

}
```

Below is how I use it

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;
    private Button stopButton;
    private ExtAudioRecorder recorder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recorder = ExtAudioRecorder.getInstanse(true);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.generateWav);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                recorder.setOutputFile("testwav.wav");
                recorder.prepare();
                recorder.reset();
                recorder.start();
                Log.i("LOG", "Working");
            }
        });


        stopButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopRecord);
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                recorder.stop();
                Log.i("LOG", "Record Done");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But all I get when I click on the `Record Wav` is an error. Those errors are below

```
ExtAudioRecorder: prepare() method called on illegal state
ExtAudioRecorder: start() called on illegal state
```

How can I fix this please? If there is any other solution, that is also fine. I just need to write wav files which I can upload into this service - https://speech-to-text-demo.mybluemix.net/

Comment: Have you tried debugging your app? Check to see what happens in prepare() and start(), set breakpoints there

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the `ExtAudioRecorder` wrong.

You said you wanted to record a `wav` file, so you should pass `false` to `getInstanse`. (The API's are a little inconsistent, `getInstanse` asks `recordingCompressed` while the constructor takes `uncompressed` which are contradictory.)

As to why `prepare` is failing, I am not really sure, more logs would be helpful.